# Is the uncertainty of the resistor the same as the uncertainty of the multimeter that was used to measure the resistance

Tags: electrical-resistance

If I am measuring the resistance of a resistor using a multimeter, and the multimeter has a known uncertainty of 2%, then is the uncertainty in the multimeter the same as the uncertainty of the resistor. Or would the uncertainty of the resistor be different.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine measuring a resistor that shows 100 ohms and 10% tolerance.

That resistor has a specific resistance right now (we’re ignoring change with age, humidity, temperature, etc)

If you measure it as 104 ohms with a 2% meter, you know it to 2%. You expect the real value to be roughly 102 to 106 ohms. But you still expect it has a specific real value in there.

On the other hand, if you just pick one of those, without measuring, you expect it to be between 90 and 110. Different ones from different batches will have different real values in that wide range, but each will have a specific value.

So you can have a 10% resistor and measure it to much closer than 10%

Answer (score 0):

The uncertainty in the multimeter is the measurement uncertainty. The apparatus that you use will always have some sort of uncertainty associated with them; this has nothing to do with the resistor. The resistor will have its own tolerance.

The tolerance and the uncertainty however, will propagate together to create a larger uncertainty in the value of your resistor.

Comment: So when measuring the total uncertainty in the resistance, will I need to combine the uncertainty in the resistor and the uncertainty in the multimeter?

Comment: Yes as both will contribute to your final reading

Comment: Actually, the resistor has a definite value.  The tolerance is just the variance of that definite value from the labeled value of the resistor.  Therefore, the 2 % uncertainty in the meter measurement is 2 % of that definite value, the tolerance does not enter that at all.  The tolerance only shows the allowance of variation by the manufacturer of the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

The uncertainty at that moment lies with the meter. For example if you have a 100 ohm resistor with a 5% tolerance then you know its value must lie somewhere between 95 and 105 ohms. Suppose you measure it, to an accuracy of 2%, as 98 ohms. You then know that the actual value of that particular resistor at that particular moment is somewhere between 96 and 100 ohms.

But resistors are not absolutely constant. Their values can drift with temperature, age and other environmental effects. So you might measure it again one day, with the same meter, and get a slightly different value.